# MASM function not returning the right value

Tags: c, assembly, masm

I need to call the function that adds 3 three integers from an assembly code;
Integers themselves are set in the assembly part;

Everything looks right, but the masm function doesn't seem to return the right value. It's stored in the eax and should be returned as a function value, but when running the C code, it doesn't printf anything, and wanted value (of 15 in this case) is actually the exit code of the program. So is there a way I can print this result?

MASM code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
.DATA
a1 DWORD 6
a2 DWORD 5
a3 DWORD 4
.CODE

func_asm PROC C

push a3
push a2
push a1

EXTRN numbers: proc
call numbers 
leave
ret
func_asm ENDP 
END
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int __cdecl func_asm();
int numbers(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    printf("%d", func_asm());
}
int numbers(int a1, int a2, int a3)
{
    return a1 + a2 + a3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, turns out, that you have to push eax before returning the value
And before that we need to create a stack itself, so the final code will be:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
.STACK
.DATA
 a1 DWORD 6
 a2 DWORD 5
 a3 DWORD 4
.CODE
func_asm PROC C

push ebp
mov ebp, esp

push a3
push a2
push a1

EXTRN numbers: proc

call numbers 
push eax
leave
ret
func_asm ENDP

END
```

C code remains unchanged

Comment: No, you don't have to `push eax`.  You do need to have EBP set up as a frame pointer for `leave` to work: it's a compact version of `mov esp,ebp` ; `pop ebp`.  That was your only problem; doing an extra push before leave is always meaningless.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you very much